# Get rid of name@os in terminal tabs

Tags: bash, terminal

How can I get rid of `name@os` in my terminal's tabs? It takes away space.

[image: Red circles denote the parts I do not want in the terminal window.]

I would like to see just the path in the tab. How to do this, please?

Comment: Show us your `PS1` variable

Comment: Thanks, Gilles, you lead me to the solution by just asking questions. The best way to help!

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the following part in the `.bashrc`. The out commented part is how it originally was set up by the Distro (Linux Mint).

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
  # PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

`\u` means *user* and `\h` means *host*.

For the records, this is the full fragment in my `.bashrc` which defines `PS1`. The first change changes the prompt, the second changes the tabs.

```bash
# ...

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
  # PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    PS1='\[\e[1;37;44m\]>\[\e[00m\] '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
  # PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# ...
```